# Importing canvas html with its js to angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm don't know, how to import external canvas file to the **AngularJS(v 1.5)** component. The canvas which I've is exported using "Adobe Animate CC", so I've two files one "html" and other "js" file. I'm completely unaware of how to add canvas to component template, what is the best way of doing it. I tried the following way but its not working :

```
<div ng-include="'components/loader/canvas-tmpl/canvas_tmpl.html'"></div>
```

Please help me with this, any suggestions?

Comment: html should included with ng-include, for your js code i would suggest you to import it on a service and use inside component controller

Comment: Thanks for you response, but exported html itself have script link to js file, still i have to create service for it?

Comment: not nessesary but is a good practice to put ur logic inside services . apart from that how you will handle your js if its not in the angular context ? if you could create a plnkr reproducing the issue it would be great

Comment: you can either move your script tag included in canvas_tmpl.html to where the rest of your app's js is loaded, or create a directive and move the js code inside a controller/service

Comment: Thanks to both of you, @Panos K you are correct, handling outer js code in angular context is bit difficult. So as SuperVeetz said, I moved the code inside the controller, so its working now!!